# How do I change server icon in discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have looked everywhere, and I cannot figure out how to do this.
I want to change the icon of a guild with the slash command.
Please help!!

I tried this:

```js
  if (interaction.commandName === 'changeicon') {
    const guild = interaction.guild;
    const iconURL = interaction.options.getString('iconurl'); // URL of the new icon image

    // Create the GuildEditData object
    const guildData = new GuildEditData().setIcon(iconURL);

    // Update the guild with the new icon
    await guild.edit(guildData);

    await interaction.reply(`Server icon changed to ${iconURL}`);
  }
});
```

and it didnt work
and i tried this

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.content == "editguild") {
        try {
            await message.guild.setIcon("./icon.png");
            await message.guild.setName("Guild name");
            message.channel.send("Successfully changed guild name and icon.");
        } catch {
            message.channel.send("There was an error setting the guild name and icon!");
        }
    }
});
```

but that's deprecated

Comment: The documentation suggests that `guild.setIcon()` is not depreciated https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Guild?scrollTo=setIcon